# How to create the rule for users in odoo11

Tags: odoo-10, odoo-11

How to **create** the **rule** for users in odoo11. I want to show particular menu item to manager only not to user. Here, I created the group for user and manager but unable to create rule for user. My code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<odoo>
    <data noupdate="1">
        <record model="ir.module.category" id="rights_current_weather">
            <field name="name">Weather Info</field> 
            <field name="sequence">2</field>
        </record>

        <record id="rights_current_weather_user" model="res.groups">
            <field name="name">User</field>
            <field name="category_id" ref="rights_current_weather"/>
            <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
        </record>

        <record id="rights_current_weather_manager" model="res.groups">
            <field name="name">Manager</field>
            <field name="category_id" ref="rights_current_weather"/>
            <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('rights_current_weather_user'))]"/>
            <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root'))]"/>
        </record>

    </data>
</odoo>
```

Answer (score 0):

After creating a rule, you need add groups to attribute on menu item 
for example:-
If you want to show a menu for the particular user code like

```
<menuitem
        id="sub_menu"
        parent="main_menu"
        name="Sub Menu1"
        groups="weather.group_manager"
        action="weather.sub_menu_action"/>
```

or you can also give groups at the field level

```
 <record id="weather.weather_menu_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">form</field>
        <field name="model">my.app</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form>
                  <field name="name"/>
                  <field name="description"/>
                  <field name="verified_at" groups="weather.rights_current_weather_manager"/>
            </form>
        </field>
</record>
```

[EDIT]

in your code, two groups

1.User (rights_current_weather_user)
this user inhrited from "base.group_user"

2.Manager (rights_current_weather_manager)
manager user inhrited from "rights_current_weather_user"

which means base.group_user > User > Manager

now if you want to hide some menu for "User". and show only for "Manager", add an attribute to menuitem groups="weather.rights_current_weather_manager" now when you login with "User" you cannot see that menu

now about the rule, a record rule restricts the access rights
for example:-
you want to show only today weather data for "User" you can code like

```
<record id="today_weather_data_only" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">Only Today Data For User</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="weather.model_name"/>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4,ref('weather.rights_current_weather_user'))]"/>
    <field name="perm_read" eval="1"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="0"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="0"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="0" />
    <field name="domain_force">[('state','=','today')]</field>
</record>
```

when "User" login,it will only show today data.

Comment: can you explain **groups at the field level** what does it mean ??? @Anshuman Sharma